# Adding an Image to tableview when clicked the More button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the `iPod` application in my `iphone`, i see a `more` button in the `tabbar` controller. When i click it i see the other `tabs` that are not shown in the `tababrcontroller`.

I need to know how to add an image in front of the name in the `tableview` that appears as a result of clicking the `More` button.

Here's an [image that will show you what exactly i want to achieve](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/5-blog-pics/apple-iphone-ipod-more.png)

2.) How to add an image to a button, finally it should appear in the format [image][text]

Comment: I am sure that this question has already been asked

Comment: If so why don't you post a few links to prove. there's no point down voting !

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this for each View Controller that you'll be adding to your Tab Bar:

```
viewTab1controller = [[ViewTab1Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewTab1" bundle:nil];
viewTab1controller.title = @"Title";

navigationTab1Controller = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewTab1controller] autorelease];
navigationTab1Controller.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] autorelease];

[viewTab1controller release];
```

If you do it for each "tab" it should work for the other icons.

Comment: So this should be added in the `appDelegate` ?

Comment: Yes thats right. or where ever the `UITabBarController` is created.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];
```

Where cell is the UITableViewCell

Comment: Won't work for this particular case, developers don't have direct access to the `UITableView` used for the "More" button. Although this is an example of adding images to a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: ugh..why does he have the tableviewcell highlighted in red in the image then. Did he just want a tabar image?

Comment: Its an example of the outcome off adding the icon to a tabbar, that tableview isn't created by the user, but by the APIs

Comment: Yes Amit Shah is right, The tableview isn't created by me, its created by the API